# moment toISOstring without modifying date

Tags: momentjs

I have a date like "Thu Sep 01 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)" which I need to send to server as ISO-8601 utc time. I tried like :

```
moment(mydate).toISOString()

moment.utc(mydate).toISOString()

moment(mydate).utcOffset("+00:00").toISOString()
```

but I am getting the result like

```
2016-08-31T18:30:00.000Z
```

which is 1day behind my intended time. So what can I do to make moment ignore my local timezone and see it as UTC?

Edit:
The expected output is

```
2016-09-01T18:30:00.000Z
```

And no, the initial input isn't a string rather a javascript "new Date()" value.

Comment: That's because it's applying the GMT offset during the UTC pairing. You'll need to rewrite the date you declare it as UTC? So do a string replace over the GMT+0530 etc part to UTC? Or am I not understanding what you are trying to accomplish here?

Comment: I think what you want is to ignore the offset field when you parse the date. Try this blog post: https://maggiepint.com/2016/05/14/moment-js-shows-the-wrong-date/

Comment: Please clarify - is the input a `Date` object that just has that string representation when logging to the console or calling `.toString()`? or is the input actually a `String`?  Also, can you edit your question to show the expected output you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I take the same problem today and find the solution.

Here is the solution: **moment(date,moment.ISO_8601)**

```
  var date = new Date();
  console.log("Original Date");
  console.log(date);
  console.log("After Moment Format");
  console.log(moment(date,moment.ISO_8601));
```

Test Execution:

[image: Test Execution]

Moment Documentation: [MomentJs](https://momentjs.com/docs/)

Answer (score 3):

**Reason this happens:**
This happens because .toISOString() returns a timestamp in UTC, even if the moment in question is in local mode. This is done to provide consistency with the specification for native JavaScript Date .toISOString()

**Solution:**
Use the same function and pass true value to it. This will prevent UTC Conversion.
`moment(date).toISOString(true)`

```js
const date = new Date("2020-12-17T03:24:00");
const dateISOStringUTC = moment(date).toISOString();
const dateISOString = moment(date).toISOString(true);

console.log("Converted to UTC:" + dateISOStringUTC)
console.log("Actual Date value:" + dateISOString)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.29.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```